# How to split a comma separated xml string when xml contains comma in it?

Tags: java

I have a string which contains multiple xml structures as below:

```
String str = "<a><f dof=\"x,y\" /></a>,<a><f dof=\"m,n\" /></a>";
```

Now I want to split this string using comma separator. But I can't do **str.split(",")**  as this will give me 4 different string. Also I can't do **str.split(">*<")** because it will remove end and start brackets from splitted string. I think I can use Pattern class of java but I am not sure about the pattern which I should use.

I can not use xml parser as the string is not a valid xml if you see properly.

Can anyone suggest me the way to split the string as per my requirement?

Comment: you can use indexOf and substring

Comment: Hey... I can have multiple such xml in single string. I don't think this will work

Comment: This is unfortunately a poorly designed format. Any chance to change that to be XML?

Comment: @Madhusudan Yeah, from where did you get this format? You should smack the designer of it with a teaspoon.

Comment: @MCEmperor It is not about format Sir. I have good xml data. But when I fetch some meta for some field and if it has multiple vale (value is a xml) so while fetching all meta values will be added with comma separation. This is default behavior. SO I have comma separated xml and I want to deal with individual xml from it.

Comment: @Madhusudan But the result is that it is (somewhat) difficult to parse. In fact two formats are used: XML and comma-separated values. Personally, I think that's a bad habit. An alternative would be to put the XML elements inside another XML node, for example: `<yns:metaElement><a><f dof="x,y" /></a></yns:metaElement><yns:metaElement><a><f dof="m,n" /></a></yns:metaElement>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest and safest way to proceed here would be to go upstream to the source of your XML and fix the formatting there.  This not being possible, you could try to strip all commas separating XML tags using something like the following:

```
String str = "<a><f dof=\"x,y\" /></a>,<a><f dof=\"m,n\" /></a>";
str = str.replaceAll("(</\\.*>)\\s*,\\s*(<.*?>)", "$1$2");
System.out.println(str);
```

Now you might have a well formed XML string which can be parsed using standard means.

**Output:**

```
<a><f dof="x,y" /></a><a><f dof="m,n" /></a>
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: What if the comma should be preserved like in <p><a>...</a>,<a>...</a></p>?

Comment: @Henry That isn't valid XML as far as I know.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the solution. In my case the string will contains all meta values as comma separated. And I want to process each meta separately. That is why I want to split the string for comma delimiter.  But I will see if I could follow the steps given by you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is, XML can contain text content.

Comment: @Madhusudan Use one of the answers/comments given here to scrub your data, and then use an XML _parser_ to work with the XML data.  Don't try to split or regex your way through it.

Comment: @Henry Then my solution would fail, and we'd need to do some parsing, but I gave the caveat that the best option is to fix the XML before bringing it into Java.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen fair enough, I just don't like to work around design problems (the data format in this case) with only partly working solutions. In most cases they will break sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

First of all replace comma between `'>' & '<'` with some other character, For example, `'#'`

Like this,

```
String str = "<a><f dof=\"x,y\" /></a>,<a><f dof=\"m,n\" /></a>";

str = str.replaceAll(">,<",">#<");
```

And than slipt it by that new character,

```
String[] strArray = str.split("#");
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Yes. This can be a way. Good Idea.

Comment: counter example: <p><a>...</a>,<a>...</a></p> where you don't want to split at the comma.

Comment: This will not be my case. Because I will be having valid xml structures separated by comma. So this scenario is not applicable for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148847/discussion-between-madhusudan-and-henry).

Comment: Henry is right. `<p><a>someAnchorContent</a>,<a>someAnchorContent</a></p>` is valid XML. That sole comma in the middle is a text node. It is completely valid to place it there. So I think a comma-separated list of XML strings is simply a bad design.